# How to create a bigger stronger text shadow

Tags: css

I am trying to replicate an image in css which should be possible. But the shadow / radius is way smaller and barely noticable with css. How can I increase the strongness / radius?

How I want it to be:

[image]

How it is with css (when I increase the radius it becomes barely noticeable):

[image]

My code:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you just need to stack multiple shadows in order to achieve the desired effect:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #fff, 0px 0px 20px #fff;
}
```

and a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4o6L4owd/